# yii2 Как сохранить состояние формы после отправки ajax запроса

Tags: php, ajax, yii2, radiobutton

Я делаю систему тестирования- приложение которое может создавать тесты для прохождения- и у меня простенький вопрос на который я не могу найти ответ - у меня есть форма с вопросом ответами и переключатель на следующий вопрос - так вот - при переключении на след вопрос - форма моя отправляется ajax методом post и соответственно - все мои галочки напротив ответов сбрасываются - [image: введите сюда описание изображения]как сохранить состоянии формы - или как сделать - что бы та часть в которой ответы с галочками не отправлялась вообще(я использую pjax)? Я прикреплю скриншот - чтобы вы видели.

Comment: при отправке через ajax галочки не сбрасываются. Инфа 146%

Comment: Хранить данные отмеченных ответов в локалсторадже. Если там есть данные, то отмечать радиобаттоны, если нет, то не отмечать.

Comment: fedornabilkin, спасибо - так и реализую!